# prepared statements don't work

Tags: php, mysql

```
if(isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
     $message=$_POST['message'];
     $cid=$_POST['cid'];
     $user_id=$_SESSION['id'];
     $stmt=$conn->prepare("update comments set message=? where id=? and user_id=?");
     $stmt->bind_param("sss",$message,$cid,$user_id);
     if(!$stmt->execute()){
          echo "error";
     } else {
          echo "success";
     }
```

I always get success but when I go to the database I find out that nothing is changed.

Comment: Please add the schema of your comments table?

Comment: Also might help to show a short database dump of what exists there to see if your 'where' clause is actually matching a real row in the table.

Comment: my table schema is 
id 
user_id
message
date

Comment: Are you sure id and user_id are strings?

Comment: Please don't ask the same question multiple times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to do an UPDATE with a WHERE clause. If it does not actually update anything, it will still be considered a success. The reason !$stmt->execute() would happen, is if there is a sql error, and it bails.

So what you should be doing, is also check if num rows affected.

```
if ( ! $stmt->affected_rows ) { echo 'nothing changed!'; }
```